# Can we always exploit Taylor's approximation in order to avoid using l'Hopital rule?

Tags: limits, taylor-expansion, limits-without-lhopital

We are given two  functions, namely: $f, g: U^\circ\subset \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ where $0 \in \overline{U}$.

Suppose you want to compute the limit  $$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$$
and that $\lim_{x \to 0} f(x) = \lim_{x\to 0} g(x) = 0$. 
In addition, suppose that l'Hopital's theorem hypothesis are satisfied and that exploiting l'Hopital rule we found that $$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)} = L \in \{\mathbb{R}, \pm\infty\}.$$
Can the same result be obtained using Taylor's approximation?
And if we consider instead $\lim_{x \to +\infty} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ anything changes?

My speculations and question's motivation follow.

In order  to apply Taylor's approximation one has to choose a function, an approximation point and an order of approximation.
Taylor's formula gives us two objects: a polynomial and a reminder.
But the only thing we know about the reminder is its behavior near the approximation point.
So in order to apply Taylor to the functions $f,g$ we have to  choose  0 as approximation point (otherwise how can we get rid of the reminder?).
It follows that $f,g$  have to be defined in $0$.
This can be problematic, for example if $f(x) = \log(x) $ and $g(x) = x^{-1}$
we can apply l'Hopital's rule and get to $$ \frac{-x^2}{x} \to 0.$$
But we are unable to expand $f$ or $g$ near $0$ as them are not defined in $0$.

So it seems to me that Taylor  method alone cannot cover all cases of interest. But I must  be wrong since I've read  [Why are people so interested in finding limits without l'Hôpital's rule?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/13008/why-are-people-so-interested-in-finding-limits-without-lh%C3%B4pitals-rule?rq=1) and I figured out that many people rely only on Taylor's method (which is a beautiful thing in my opinion) and that in some universities L'Hopital's rule use is even discouraged.

Comment: Does differentiability imply existence of the Taylor series?

Comment: We can use for sure a first order approximation of $f,g$ in an open interval with endpoint $0$.  But it would be interesting also to consider the case where $f$ and $g$ are defined and differentiable at  $0$ or are analytic.

Comment: L'Hospital's rule is *equivalent* to the use of first order approximations — which are more commendable than L'Hospital's rule

Comment: This is exactly the statement I was searching for, where can I find the  proof?